# MongoDB: Replication set + sharding: Sort error

Tags: mongodb, sorting

My environment: Version: 2.4.4, OS: Linux 64-bit, components: Replication Set + sharding

When I connect to my database using `mongos`, one error appears:

```
mongos> db.test.find().limit(500).sort({TIME:-1})

error: {
    "$err" : "BSONObj size: 268823536 (0xF0EB0510) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: \u001f: ?type=38",
    "code" : 10334
}
```

However, when I sort by another field, there is no error:

```
mongos> db.test.find().limit(500).sort({C_ID:-1})

{ "_id" : "13744759060340298528dbaaa", "C_ID" : "999", "TIME" : ISODate("2013-07-22T06:51:46.034Z"), "SE" : "0", "AREA" : "a21", "CT1" : "1", "CT2" : "1", "S_PT" : 11, "EN_N" : "Test system", "T_ID" : "3946", "EN_T" : "2", "MSG" : "for test64", "EVENT" : "test event39", "S_IP" : "1.2.4.174", "URL" : "URL536" }
......
```

So I connect to one of the shardings:

```
sh0:PRIMARY> db.test.find().limit(500).sort({TIME:-1})

{ "_id" : "13744759061349b294b309aaa", "C_ID" : "373", "TIME" : ISODate("2013-07-22T06:51:46.134Z"), "SE" : "0", "AREA" : "a2", "CT1" : "1", "CT2" : "8", "S_PT" : 8, "EN_N" : "Test system", "T_ID" : "2654", "EN_T" : "1", "MSG" : "for test0", "EVENT" : "test event38", "S_IP" : "1.2.4.193", "URL" : "URL829" }
...
```

Anyone gives me an idea?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: in a sharded environment, you must pass shard key as one of the parameters in your queries otherwise mongos will query all the shards and combine results which is a performance disaster. Is C_ID your shard key?

Comment: Yes, C_ID is the shard key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass shard key to all your queries. That's not a recommendation, it's a rule you must follow. Additionally, index all the parameters you need in queries. For queries which require multiple parameters create compound indexes. NOTE: since your shard key will be part of all your queries, single indexes will be of little use, you must create compound keys only. For example, to query based on TIME, you need to create a compound index - {C_ID, TIME}, in that order if you pass the parameters in that order in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `TIME` field indexed ?

Index it

```
db.test.ensureIndex({TIME : -1})
```

Comment: It is not indexed,I will have a try.Thanks for your reply!